# What types to add for methods using react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i want to add types to methods passed as props from parent to child component using react and typescript.

below is my code,

```
function Parent() {
    const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = React.useState(false);
    return (
        <Child setIsClicked={setIsClicked} >
            <div> somediv</div>
        </Child>
    );
 }

 interface Props {
     setIsClicked: any; //instead of any what type should be used here
 }
 function Child ({setIsClicked, children}: Props) {
     return (
         <div onClick={setIsClicked}>
             {children}
         </div>
     );
  }
```

As you see from above code, i am using any as type for setIsClicked method. this works. but i know that this is not the right way to do it.

could someone help me with this. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most precise type for that a setter function for type `T` is:

```
React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<T>>,
```

So you can do:

```
setIsClicked: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Boolean>>
```

But that's a bit wordy and sometimes requires import boilerplate you don't want. Often, denoting the type as a plain function that accepts the type as an argument is sufficient:

```
setIsClicked: (newClicked: boolean) => void
```

Comment: thanks. there is another child2 comp that takes this prop like setIsClicked? : (newClicked:boolean) => void and in return ( <Another setIsClicked={setIsClicked}/>) here it shows error '((value: boolean) => void) | undefined' is not assignable to type '(value: boolean) => void'.

Comment: Your `?` is making the prop optional. Either remove the `?`, or assert that you know that it exists: `setIsClicked={setIsClicked!}`

Answer (score 1):

The setter function accepts a value or a callback function which may complicate things a little bit. What I would suggest is to create a separate function to handle the onclick instead of passing the setter directly. It's more readable and cleaner.

Also remember to use the generic type when using `useState` hook.

```
function Parent() {
   const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = React.useState<Boolean>(false);
   const handleClick = (value: boolean) => {
      setIsClicked(value);
   };
   
   return (
      <Child setIsClicked={handleClick}>
          <div>somediv</div>
      </Child>
   );
}

interface Props {
    setIsClicked: (value: boolean) => void;
}
```

Comment: It really depends on the scale of the component. Here, `handleClick` is just noise IMO.

Comment: @EmileBergeron I'd still use this approach instead of using `Dispatch` type as it is in the marked answer. IMO.

Comment: The accepted answer has both, I'd probably use a simple function type as well, but I wouldn't wrap it in an arrow function until I need it for something else.

Answer (score 1):

That's how I would do it:

```
const Parent: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClick = React.useCallback(() => {
    setIsClicked(true)
  }, []);

  return (
    <Child onClick={handleClick}>
      <div> somediv</div>
    </Child>
  );
}

interface Props {
  onClick: React.UIEventHandler<HTMLDivElement>
}

const Child: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ onClick, children }) => {
  return (
    <div onClick={onClick}>{children}</div>
  )
}
```

- ✅ `handleClick` is a generic click handler. No coupling to React hooks. The caller (Parent) can do whatever it chooses when the Child is clicked.
- ✅ The Parent receives the event object, but is free to discard it. In this scenario the event object is discarded, but the Child willingly exposes it — it doesn't know how it's going to be used, which is desirable.
- ✅ `handleClick` is memoized thanks to `React.useCallback`